# RFJS validation show error message with key, not label

Tags: reactjs, jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

Using https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io to render a form based on a json schema I can define validation for every field. This is great and easy, the only thing I am looking for is a way to create a more meaning full validation error.

E.g.

Schema:

```
{
  "title": "Contextualized errors",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "First name",
      "minLength": 8,
      "pattern": "\\d+"
    },
  }
}
```

This provides validation and returns an error text like:

- firstName: should NOT be shorter than 8 characters
- firstName: should match pattern "\d+"

I want to change this first part, into 'First name' or even translate it. How am I possible to do this?

---

**EDIT**

I assume it would be possible to define `firstName` as `First name`, which would require some 'complex' remapping with formData object to actual keys.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you can define your own Validation error for that.

```
validate = (formData, errors) => {

 if(formData.firstName.length<8){
     errors.firstName.addError('First name can be of 8 or more character long') // your custom error
   }
 else if(formData.firstName.search(regexPattern)){
     errors.firstName.addError('First name should match your given pattern')
  }

  return errors;

 };
```

and then just pass this function to your Form.

```
  <Form
        ...
        validate={this.validate}
        showErrorList={false}
        .
        .
        .
      />
```